# Cross the yard without getting wet

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is the question:

> There is a house with a backyard which is square bounded by
>   coordinates (0,0) in the southwest to (1000,1000) in
>   the northeast. In this yard there are a number of water sprinklers
>   placed to keep the lawn soaked in the middle of the summer. However, 
>   it might or might not be possible to cross the yard without getting
>   soaked and without leaving the yard?
>
> Input The input starts with a line containing an integer 1≤n≤1000, the
>   number of water sprinklers. A line follows for each sprinkler,
>   containing three integers: the (x,y)(x,y) location of the sprinkler
>   (0≤x,y,≤10000) and its range r (1≤r≤1000). The sprinklers will soak
>   anybody passing strictly within the range of the sprinkler (i.e.,
>   within distance strictly less than r).
>
> The house is located on the west side (x=0) and a path is needed to
>   the east side of the yard (x=1000).
>
> Output If you can find a path through the yard, output four real
>   numbers, separated by spaces, rounded to two digits after the decimal
>   place. These should be the coordinates at which you may enter and
>   leave the yard, respectively. If you can enter and leave at several
>   places, give the results with the highest y. If there is no way to get
>   through the yard without getting soaked, print a line containing
>   “IMPOSSIBLE”.

Sample Input

```
3
500 500 499
0 0 999
1000 1000 200
```

Sample output

```
0.00 1000.00 1000.00 800.00
```

Here is my thought process:

- Define circle objects with x,y,r and write a function to determine if a given point is wet or not(inside the circle or not) on the circumference is not wet btw.

  ```
  class circle {
     int h;
     int k;
     int r;

  public:
     circle();
     circle(int h, int k, int r){
         this->h = h;
         this->k = k;
         this->r = r;
     };

     bool iswet(pair<int,int>* p){
         if (pow(this->r - 0.001, 2)  > (pow(p->first - this->h, 2) + 
             pow(p->second - this->k, 2) ) ) {
             return true; 
         }     
         else
           return false;
     };
  ```
- Then implement a depth first search, prioritizing to go up and right whenever possible.

However since circles are not guaranteed to be pass on integer coordinates an the result is expected in floats with double precision (xxx.xx). So if we keep everything in integers the grid suddenly becomes 100,000 x 100,000 which is way too big. Also the time limit is 1 sec.
So I thought ok lets stick to 1000x1000 and work with floats instead. Loop over int coordinates and whenever I hit a sprinkle just snap in the perimeter of the circle since we are safe in the perimeter. But in that case could not figure out how DFS work.

Here is the latest trial

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int MAXY = 1e3;
const int MAXX = 1e3;
const int MINY = 0;
const int MINX = 0;

struct pair_hash {
    inline std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<int,int> & v) const {
        return v.first*31+v.second;
    }
};


class circle {
    int h;
    int k;
    int r;

  public:

    circle();
    circle(int h, int k, int r){
        this->h = h;
        this->k = k;
        this->r = r;
    };
    bool iswet(pair<float,float>* p){
        if (pow(this->r - 0.001, 2)  > (pow(p->first - this->h, 2) + pow(p->second - this->k, 2) ) ) {
            this->closest_pair(p);
            return true; 
        }
        else
            return false;
    };

    void closest_pair(pair<float,float>* p){
            float vx = p->first - this->h;
            float vy = p->second - this->k; 
            float magv = sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy); 
            p->first = this->h + vx / magv * this->r;
            p->second = this->k + vy / magv * this->r;
    }
};


static bool test_sprinkles(vector<circle> &sprinkles, pair<float,float>* p){


    for (int k = 0; k < sprinkles.size(); k++)
        if (sprinkles[k].iswet(p)) return false; 
    return true;

}

int main(){
    int n; // number of sprinkles 
    while (cin >> n){
        vector<circle> sprinkles_array;
        sprinkles_array.reserve(n);
        int h, k, r;
        while (n--){
          cin >> h >> k >> r;
          sprinkles_array.push_back(circle(h, k, r));
        }/* code */

        pair<float,float> enter = make_pair(0, MAXY);
        deque<pair<float,float>> mystack; 
        mystack.push_back(enter);
        pair<float,float>* cp;
        bool found = false;
        unordered_set<pair<float, float>, pair_hash> visited;


        while (!mystack.empty()){
            cp = &mystack.back(); 
            if (cp->first == MAXX) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            visited.insert(*cp);

            if (cp->second > MAXY || cp->second < MINY || cp ->first < MINX ) {
                visited.insert(*cp);
                mystack.pop_back();
                continue;
            }
            if (!test_sprinkles(sprinkles_array,cp))  {      
                continue;
            }
            pair<int,int> newpair = make_pair(cp->first, cp->second + 1);
            if (visited.find(newpair) == visited.end())  {      
                mystack.push_back(newpair);
                continue;
            }
            else visited.insert(newpair);

            newpair = make_pair(cp->first + 1 , cp->second);
            if (visited.find(newpair) == visited.end())  {      
                mystack.push_back(newpair);
                continue;
            }
            else visited.insert(newpair);

            newpair = make_pair(cp->first, cp->second - 1);
            if (visited.find(newpair) == visited.end())  {      
                mystack.push_back(newpair);
                continue;
            }
            else visited.insert(newpair);

            newpair = make_pair(cp->first - 1, cp->second);
            if (visited.find(newpair) == visited.end())  {      
                mystack.push_back(newpair);
                continue;
            }
            else visited.insert(newpair);

            mystack.pop_back();
        }
        cout << setprecision(2);
        cout << fixed;
        if (found){
            double xin = mystack.front().first;
            double yin = mystack.front().second;
            pair <float, float>  p = mystack.back();
            p.second++;
            for (int k = 0; k < sprinkles_array.size(); k++)
                if (sprinkles_array[k].iswet(&p)) break;   
            double xout = p.first;
            double yout = p.second;


            cout << xin << " " << yin << " " << xout << " " << yout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "IMPOSSIBLE" << endl;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: you may consider the sprinkler intersections as nodes and delimit the valid walks whether there exists a path linking borders (a path from south to north makes a walk impossible, a path from west (0, y_i) to north makes all y_j, j > i as starting point invalid

Comment: I'd say you're looking at the problem the wrong way, it doesn't ask you to find a path, just the boundaries. To me that means you should ignore the actual path and try to find the connected components - think about sets of connected circles, and how they can affect your ability to go from one point to another on the perimeter.

Comment: @JosephIreland is right.  See also the related game Hex.  Figuring out how to make the path is harder than figuring out whether the path is blocked.

Comment: Yep I think I understand. Wouldn't think it would be that easy.

Comment: A very basic idea to solve the problem (probably not the fastest, but the easiest) could be to use a flood fill algorithm, starting the flooding in the west. There is a path, if there is a flood-filled pixel in the east. Just think of the grid as a bitmap. Or if you are lazy, render a 1000x1000 bitmap from the data and use the Gimp ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes @JosephIreland is right. Solved it with grouping intersecting (not touching) circles. Then these groups have maxy and min y coordinates. If it exceeds the yard miny and maxy the way is blocked.

Then these groups also have upper and lower intersection points with x=0 and x=1000 lines. If the upper points are larger than the yard maxy then the maximum entry/exit points are lower entery points.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int MAXY = 1e3;
const int MAXX = 1e3;
const int MINY = 0;
const int MINX = 0;

struct circle {
    int h;
    int k;
    int r;
    float maxy;
    float miny;

    circle();
    circle(int h, int k, int r){
        this->h = h;
        this->k = k;
        this->r = r;
        this->miny = this->k - r;
        this->maxy = this->k + r;

    };
};



struct group {

    float maxy = -1;
    float miny = -1;
    vector<circle*> circles;
    float upper_endy = -1;
    float upper_starty = -1;
    float lower_endy = -1;
    float lower_starty = -1;



    void add_circle(circle& c){

        if ((c.maxy > this->maxy) || this->circles.empty() )  this->maxy = c.maxy;
        if ((c.miny < this->miny) || this->circles.empty() )  this->miny = c.miny;
        this->circles.push_back(&c);

        // find where it crosses x=minx and x= maxx
        float root = sqrt(pow(c.r, 2) - pow(MINX - c.h, 2));
        float y1 = root + c.k;
        float y2 = -root + c.k;

        if (y1 > this->upper_starty) this->upper_starty = y1;
        if (y2 > this->lower_starty) this->lower_starty = y2;

        root = sqrt(pow(c.r, 2) - pow(MAXX - c.h, 2));
        y1 = root + c.k;
        y2 = -root + c.k;
        if (y1 > this->upper_endy) this->upper_endy = y1;
        if (y2 > this->lower_endy) this->lower_endy = y2;

    };
    bool does_intersect(circle& c1){
        for(circle* c2 : circles){
            float dist = sqrt(pow(c1.h - c2->h,2)) +  sqrt(pow(c1.k - c2->k,2));
            (dist < (c1.r + c2->r)) ? true : false;
        };    
    };

};



int main(){
    int n; // number of sprinkles 
    while (cin >> n){
        vector<circle> sprinkles_array;
        sprinkles_array.reserve(n);
        int h, k, r;
        while (n--){
          cin >> h >> k >> r;
          sprinkles_array.push_back(circle(h, k, r));
        }/* code */
        vector<group> groups;
        group newgroup;
        newgroup.add_circle(sprinkles_array[0]);
        groups.push_back(newgroup);

        for (int i = 1; i < sprinkles_array.size(); i++){ 
            bool no_group = true;
            for (group g:groups){
                if (g.does_intersect(sprinkles_array[i])){
                    g.add_circle(sprinkles_array[i]);
                    no_group = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (no_group) {
                group newgroup;
                newgroup.add_circle(sprinkles_array[i]);
                groups.push_back(newgroup);
            }
        }

        float entery = MAXY;
        float exity = MAXY;
        bool found = true;
        for (group g : groups){
            if ((g.miny < MINY) && (g.maxy > MAXY)){
                found = false;
                break;
            }
            if (g.upper_starty > entery)
                entery = g.lower_starty;
            if (g.upper_endy > exity)
                exity = g.lower_endy;
        }

        cout << setprecision(2);
        cout << fixed;
        if (found){
            cout << float(MINX) << " " << entery << " " << float(MAXX) << " " << exity << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "IMPOSSIBLE" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look quite right, if there's a set of small connected circles reaching from the middle of the start to the middle of the top, there's no way through above it, similar if it touches the bottom and you try to go below.

Comment: Also shouldn't `if (y2 > this->lower_endy)` be `if (y2 < this->lower_endy)` ?